# "Access Denied" error in Visual Studio.Net 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have converted an ASP.NET application that was developed in VS.NET 2003 to VS.NET 2010. After fixing all the build errors and running it, it works well except in one place
where I am opening a document that I just copied into a specific folder from the ASP.NET page.

I get an "Access Denied" error when I try to open the file from the ASP.NETpage. But when I go to Windows Explorer and try to view the file I dont have any problem. How might I resolve this?

Here is the code:

```
string url;
sring newurl;

url = GetDocumentPath(540450); 
if (url != null)
{   
     newurl = @"c:\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url);
     System.IO.File.Copy(url, newurl, true);
}  
Process.Start("iexplore", newurl);
```

Comment: Your login has permissions but does the asp user account have permission?

Comment: That won't work; you're running `iexplore` on the **server**.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed sounds like the user doesn't have the correct permisions, however it could also be caused by the path in newurl being a directory.

Besides it seems that your application stores files in C:\ which depending on your operating isn't accessible for users without administrator permissions (windows vista/server 2008 and up), you could try to use process monitor to find out if the correct permissions are used. See this blog post:

http://improve.dk/archive/2009/10/21/solving-access-denied-errors-using-process-monitor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ASP.net user account is not getting permissions to the folder. You need to right click the folder with the files in explorer, go to permissions and then search for the ASP user (something like ASPNET), add full folder permissions and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to consult [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668079%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on Microsoft's site.  It offers a few workarounds for these Visual Studio "Access Denied" errors.